# Renaming multiple directories

Tags: linux, bash

If have a directory structure that stores records based on their date of recording. 
Originally there was one directory that contained a subdirectory for every single day like this

- basedir

  - 2010-01-01

    - multiple files and sometimes subdirectories
  - 2010-01-02
  - ...
  - ...
  - 2014-12-15

Since that became too big for comfort, I decided to do some moving around and ended up with this:

- basedir

  - 2010

    - 01

      - 2010-01-01
      - 2010-01-02
      - ...
      - 2010-01-31
    - 02

      - 2010-02-01
      - 2010-02-02
      - ...
      - 2010-02-28
    - 03
    - ...
  - 2011
  - ...
  - 2014

So to get to todays data I would look in `basedir/2014/12/2014-12-15/`

I would like to rename all the full date subdirectories such that they have only the day of the month as name. Todays data would then be located in `basedir/2014/12/15/`.

What is the easy way to achieve this?

---

After some looking around I have created a `find` regex that specifically gives me the directories I am looking for, thereby reducing the change of messing things up.

`find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/(20[0-9]{2})/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/\1-\2-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one-liner:

```
find -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d | while read -r name; do
  mv -v "$name" "${name/????-??-}"; done
```

to be executed in `basedir`.

The line break is just for readability but technically it is a one-liner.

I highly recommend to create a backup before executing. This command does no sanity checks. It is not at all safe to execute on arbitrary trees. It will mess up with dirs that happen to have the same "date" part. It will break when there are spaces in the directory names.

But for a one time run, on data where you know that the filenames are sane, with backup, and manual verification afterwards, it is safe enough to use, once.

The `"${name/????-??-}"`part is bash specific. It might not work on other shells. It is called [search and replace in parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace).

Comment: That search and replace in parameter expansion is nice! I see what it tries to do, but it doesn't work. I made a test with only one file: testdir/2014/12/2014-12-15/dummy.dat and it complains about "No such file or directory". For more sanity checks I have now created a regex that seems to work, I'll add it to my question.

Comment: When I combine my find string with your while loop, it seems to work! Thanks

Comment: I think the original answer would have worked if he had used `-type d`. If there are blanks in the found paths it would need `while name="$(line)"; do ...`

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the changes in the question.